# Sum of binary quadratic forms over inputs of equal Hamming weight

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, finite-fields, quadratic-forms

$\DeclareMathOperator{\field}{\mathbb{F}}$
Let $n$ be a positive integer, and let $q : \field_2^{n} \rightarrow \field_2$ be a quadratic form, specified in coordinates as

$$q(x)=\sum_{i =1}^n \alpha_i x_i + \sum_{\substack{j,k=1\\ j<k}}^n \beta_{j,k} x_j x_k$$

for some $\alpha_i, \beta_{j,k} \in \field_2$. For each integer $a\in \{0,\dots, n\}$, I am interested in the quantity

$$ C_{q,a}=\sum_{\substack{x \in \field_2^{n}\\ |x|=a}} (-1)^{q(x)} \in \mathbb{Z},$$

where $|x|$ denotes the Hamming weight of $x$.

Is there a simple formula for $C_{q,a}$? Have these quantities $C_{q,a}$ been studied before?

Comment: Somewhat relevant paper: [Algorithms for Modular Counting of Roots of Multivariate
Polynomials](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~venkatg/pubs/papers/mod-root-count.pdf)

Comment: (sign corrected) We can compute $C_{q,a}\bmod4$ by considering $q(x)$ as a function over integers, and noticing that $(−1)^{q(x)}\equiv1+2q(x)\pmod4$. Then we have $$C_{q,a}\equiv \binom{n}{a} + 2\binom{n-1}{a-1}\sum_i \alpha_i + 2\binom{n-2}{a-2} \sum_{j<k} \beta_{j,k} \pmod{4}.$$

Comment: Thank you! Do you have any intuition for the general question? I would also be interested if you know of a well-behaved, (hopefully "small") family of $\mathbb{Z}$-valued functions on $\{0,1,\dots, n\}$ that these $C_{q,\cdot}$ must lie in.

Comment: My intuition only tells me that computing $C_{q,a}$ may be hard.

Comment: In fact, $C_{n,a}$ can be similarly computed modulo $2^m$ for $m>2$, although formulas become cumbersome as $m$ grows. So, while in principle taking $2^m>\binom{n}a$ can reveal the value of $C_{q,a}$ itself, direct computation of $C_{q,a}$ will likely be easier.